# How can I install SDL_image on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS?

Tags: sdl, ubuntu-12.04

I installed the ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I just installed a compiler to c++ programming. It's name is Anjuta. It's a free programming software. I would like to make simple games with that one, but it shows to me: `IMG_Load in-lSDL_image... no...` And `SDL_image not found`, as you can see in the picture...

I tried to google it, install it, but it won't work. What is the easiest way? Or better for beginning game programmers on linux? :-)

image file: freeimagehosting dot net/oo5dq

Answer (score -4, accepted):

SDL_Image is a library for development in C++. I suggest first getting a rad IDE to develop in - CodeBlocks is good:

http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads

Then I'd suggest following these tutorials, which will guide you into installing the relevant SDL libraries for C++ game development - SDL_Image is only one of them... and not the one I would start with:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lb_Jy5HGMsk

This got me set up with SDL and C++ development. I have since made a game with decent graphics (2D) and playability, as well as an online component using SDL_net.

Good luck!

Comment: He is hungarian too. :-) I'm from hungary too.. :-) The man, who is talking. And thanks, it look like a good tutorial... I'm on it.

Comment: He has several higher-level tutorials using OpenGL, etc. The guy and his videos are a really great resource.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY You're correct. One of my poorest responses. Sadly I do not really know the answer to this any longer as I have not touched SDL in the 4 years since. I suspect darKoram's answer would work.

Answer (score 25):

`sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev`

Found on s.o. here:
[how to install c library on linux (in particular SDL_image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102657/how-to-install-c-library-on-linux-in-particular-sdl-image)

Worked for me on ubuntu 12.04